# How to set remote DISPLAY using net-ssh gem?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use the net-ssh Ruby gem to connect to a remote workstation and start a GUI application with the DISPLAY set to the originating workstation.  Here is the code that works to connect to the selected workstation.

```
Net::SSH.start(selected_workstation, ENV['USER']) do |ssh|
  # How can I set the remote display here?
end
```

thx in advance

Comment: If you're talking about X11 forwarding though SSH with Ruby Net::SSH, then it does not seem it is supported: https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/125

Comment: You could just run the `ssh` executable instead, which supports forwarding: `system("ssh -X ...")`.

Comment: @Casper Yes, but be sure to break out arguments like `system('ssh','-X', '...')` to avoid nasty shell issues.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the tips!